# Why can't I copy the call method of a function

Tags: javascript, function

Essentially I want to wrap (not extend) a function but the wrapper shall be callable just like the function. I can use a function (Example 1 or 2) to execute the `call` function.

My question is why can't I just copy the `call` function (Example 3)? If I do this, I get the error **Function.prototype.call called on incompatible Object**

```js
function FunctionWrapper( description, functionReference ) {
    this.description = description;
    /* 1 */ this.call = function( thisArg ) { functionReference.call( thisArg ) };
    /* 2 */ this.call = thisArg => functionReference.call( thisArg );
    /* 3 */ this.call = functionReference.call;
}

function StringHolder( string ) {
    this.string = string;
}

StringHolder.prototype.log = function() {
    console.log( this.string );
};

let logger = new FunctionWrapper( "This is a logger", StringHolder.prototype.log );
logger.call( new StringHolder( "bar" ) );
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Called_on_incompatible_type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with #3 is that `this` within `call` is wrong. In #1 and #2, `this` within `call` is `functionReference` (the function passed to `FunctionWrapper`), but in #3 `this` is the `FunctionWrapper` instance, not `functionReference`. `call` expects `this` to be a function object, but your `FunctionWrapper` isn't a function, which is why it gives you that error message. More in [*How does the "this" keyword work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

If you want `logger.call( new StringHolder( "bar" ));` to work, you need to do one of these:

- Use #1, which is just fine
- Use #2, which is just fine (I'd say slightly better than #1)
- Use `bind`, e.g.:

  ```
  this.call = functionReference.call.bind(functionReference);
  ```
- Remember `functionReference` on your object and provide your own `call` that uses it.

---

Side note: Don't forget [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), `call`'s counterpart. :-)

Comment: An elaboration of what TJ writes, for clarity: Remember that `call` belongs to the `Function` prototype. So it expects that `this` refers to a function, but when you call `this.call(...)`, `this` is bound to _an object_, not a `Function`, meaning it fails to find the stuff it expects on the prototype, hence the error message. That's why you need to bind it to the functionReference, as TJ writes. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: @oligofren - Of course, functions *are* objects... :-) I should have called out the reason for the specific error in the answer (so I've done that now), thanks. :-)

Comment: okay I thought I can cheat on the context. For other methods/arguments this would work. Thank you for the explanation. And yes I won't forget apply, I just wanted to keep the example simple